# Chrome not loading tabs

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, chrome-for-android, motorola-moto-g3

I have Moto G3 XT1541 on stock Lollipop 5.1.1 and sometime tabs won't load. I just get stuck on this

[image]

Usually, I just have to close the tab and reopen it and it will work but it's quite annoying

Comment: So you're saying that reloading also doesn't work? Are you using Chrome stable or beta? Is it updated?

Comment: @Firelord Absolutely. Not using chrome beta, no update available